# Usage of pronoun la/lo

Tags: pronombres

I was doing duolingo lessons, when I stumbled onto this sentence

> Él la seguía a ella.

I translated it correctly (according to Duolingo): `He was following her`. But I am still confused with the structure of this sentence. Could it be simplified to:

> Él seguía a ella.

or even

> Él la seguía.

Don't `la` and `a ella` mean the same thing in this sentence, and in some way redundant when we use both of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't say:

> Él seguía a ella. ✖️

When the direct complement is a personal pronoun, like *ella*, you must put the redundant *la* before the verb:

> Él la seguía a ella. ✔️

If the complement is not a personal pronoun, you don't need the *la*:

> Él seguía a María. ✔️

You can also omit the complement as you guessed, but that changes the emphasis of the sentence:

> Él la seguía. ✔️

This is explained in this [RAE article](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF) about object pronouns:

> **5.1.** Si el complemento tónico es también un pronombre personal, la coaparición del pronombre átono es obligatoria, tanto si el complemento es directo como indirecto: *Me castigaron a mí*; *A ti te dieron el premio* (no *Castigaron a mí*; *A ti dieron el premio*). Aunque son posibles, en estos casos, oraciones idénticas sin el complemento tónico (*Me castigaron*; *Te dieron el premio*), existen diferencias expresivas de importancia entre ambas posibilidades: la presencia del complemento tónico denota un propósito de contraste o discriminación, ausente de la oración en la que solo aparece el pronombre átono; así, en *Me castigaron a mí*, frente a *Me castigaron*, se subraya el hecho de que ha sido solo a mí, y no a otros igualmente merecedores de ello o más culpables que yo, a quien se ha castigado.

Comment: Additional thanks, for RAE link, I still find it complicated to find there information, more complex than right form of the verb.

Answer (score 2):

The object pronoun *her* is *la*.

If we say *he was following her*, this is actually *él **la** estaba siguiendo.* (*was/were* + -ing form is *past continuous.*)

Saying *él la estaba siguiendo **a ella*** is redundant, because the object pronoun *la* tells us who we're referring to.

Comment: That's confirms what I was thinking.  And as for other part of my question, can you say: `él estaba siguiendo a ella` ?

Comment: @igormilla Yes, but it sounds a little weird to my ears.

Comment: okey, now all my curiosity is satisfied.